# Do the conjugacy classes of a group form a quotient group?

Tags: group-theory

Do the conjugacy classes of a group form a quotient group, $G / \sim$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

No. The product of two conjugacy classes is not a conjugacy class in general; instead it is some union of conjugacy classes.

However, it is possible to turn the conjugacy classes into an *algebra*, namely the [center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(algebra)) of the [group algbra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_algebra) $Z(\mathbb{C}[G])$. This is spanned by sums over conjugacy classes.

Answer (score 5):

Not in general. There is no reason to expect that the products of conjugate elements would be conjugate. IOW the product on $G/\sim$ is not necessarily well defined.

For example, if $G=S_3$, then the 2-cycles $a=(12)$ and $a'=(13)$ are conjugate, but
$aa=(1)$ and $aa'=(132)$ are not. Therefore the product of the conjugacy class $[a]$ with itself is not well-defined.

Comment: What do you mean by "product of conjugate elements would be conjugate"?

Comment: @MarshalKurosh: Simply that if $a$ and $a'$ are conjugates and $b$ and $b'$ are conjugates, it does not follow that $ab$ and $a'b'$ would be conjugates. Sorry about not making that clear.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have pointed out, this is not true in general. However, every quotient group arises by killing some set of conjugacy classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Consider the group of integers under addition, and the equiv relation defined by:

$a$ ~ $b$ iff $a=b=0$ or $a/b=2^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq 0$.

Comment: I suspect that the intention was that the equivalence relation is that of conjugation in the group?